# Attribute Position_VS_in is bound to generic attribute 0, but gl_Vertex is also used

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I am attempting to use four shaders: A vertex Shader (VS), a Tessellation Control Shader (TCS), a Tessellation Evaluation Shader (TES), and a Fragment Shader (FS).

However, when I attempt to load these shaders, I get:
[image]

This has been most baffling, and I have already spent a couple of hours trying to sort it out. However, I cannot see "gl_Vertex" anywhere in my code, so I am stuck really. I don't even know which shader is the problem.

Here is my current code for loading shaders (It looks like a lot, but it's really all just repeated code with slight changes):

```
public static int loadShaderPair(String vertexShaderLocation, String fragmentShaderLocation, String tesShaderLocation, String tesscontrolShaderLocation) {
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    int tesscontrolShader = glCreateShader(GL40.GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
    int tesShader = glCreateShader(GL40.GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER);
    StringBuilder vertexShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder fragmentShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder tesShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder tesscontrolShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader tesShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        tesShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tesShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = tesShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            tesShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (tesShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                tesShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    BufferedReader tesscontrolShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        tesscontrolShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tesscontrolShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = tesscontrolShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            tesscontrolShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (tesscontrolShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                tesscontrolShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    BufferedReader vertexShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        vertexShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vertexShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = vertexShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            vertexShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (vertexShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                vertexShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    BufferedReader fragmentShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        fragmentShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fragmentShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = fragmentShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fragmentShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (fragmentShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                fragmentShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    if (glGetShaderi(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Vertex shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 1024));
        return -1;
    }
    glShaderSource(tesscontrolShader, tesscontrolShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(tesscontrolShader);
    if (glGetShaderi(tesscontrolShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("tesscontrol shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.glGetError()));
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(tesscontrolShader, 1024));
    }
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    if (glGetShaderi(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Fragment shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.glGetError()));
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 1024));
    }
    glShaderSource(tesShader, tesShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(tesShader);
    if (glGetShaderi(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Tessellation shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(tesShader, 1024));
        return -1;
    }
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, tesShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, tesscontrolShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    if (glGetProgrami(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Shader program wasn't linked correctly.");
        System.err.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.glGetError()));
        System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 1024));
        System.exit(1);
        return -1;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(tesShader);
    glDeleteShader(tesscontrolShader);
    return shaderProgram;
}
```

And here are my shaders:
VS:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position_VS_in;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord_VS_in;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 Normal_VS_in;

uniform mat4 gWorld;

out vec3 WorldPos_CS_in;
out vec2 TexCoord_CS_in;
out vec3 Normal_CS_in;

void main()
{
WorldPos_CS_in = (gWorld * vec4(Position_VS_in, 1.0)).xyz;
TexCoord_CS_in = TexCoord_VS_in;
Normal_CS_in = (gWorld * vec4(Normal_VS_in, 0.0)).xyz;
gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

TCS:

```
// define the number of CPs in the output patch
 layout (vertices = 3) out;

uniform vec3 gEyeWorldPos;

// attributes of the input CPs
in vec3 WorldPos_CS_in[];
in vec2 TexCoord_CS_in[];
in vec3 Normal_CS_in[];

 // attributes of the output CPs
out vec3 WorldPos_ES_in[];
out vec2 TexCoord_ES_in[];
out vec3 Normal_ES_in[];

float GetTessLevel(float Distance0, float Distance1)
{
float AvgDistance = (Distance0 + Distance1) / 2.0;

if (AvgDistance <= 2.0) {
    return 10.0;
}
else if (AvgDistance <= 5.0) {
    return 7.0;
}
else {
    return 3.0;
}
}

void main()
{
// Set the control points of the output patch
TexCoord_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = TexCoord_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];
Normal_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = Normal_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];
WorldPos_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = WorldPos_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];
// Calculate the distance from the camera to the three control points
float EyeToVertexDistance0 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[0]);
float EyeToVertexDistance1 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[1]);
float EyeToVertexDistance2 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[2]);

// Calculate the tessellation levels
gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance1, EyeToVertexDistance2);
gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance2, EyeToVertexDistance0);
gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance0, EyeToVertexDistance1);
gl_TessLevelInner[0] = gl_TessLevelOuter[2];
}
```

TES:

```
layout(triangles, equal_spacing, ccw) in;

uniform mat4 gVP;
uniform sampler2D gDisplacementMap;
uniform float gDispFactor;

in vec3 WorldPos_ES_in[];
in vec2 TexCoord_ES_in[];
in vec3 Normal_ES_in[];

out vec3 WorldPos_FS_in;
out vec2 TexCoord_FS_in;
out vec3 Normal_FS_in;

vec2 interpolate2D(vec2 v0, vec2 v1, vec2 v2)
{
return vec2(gl_TessCoord.x) * v0 + vec2(gl_TessCoord.y) * v1 + vec2(gl_TessCoord.z) * v2;
}

vec3 interpolate3D(vec3 v0, vec3 v1, vec3 v2)
{
return vec3(gl_TessCoord.x) * v0 + vec3(gl_TessCoord.y) * v1 + vec3(gl_TessCoord.z) * v2;
}

void main()
{  
// Interpolate the attributes of the output vertex using the barycentric coordinates
TexCoord_FS_in = interpolate2D(TexCoord_ES_in[0], TexCoord_ES_in[1], TexCoord_ES_in[2]);
Normal_FS_in = interpolate3D(Normal_ES_in[0], Normal_ES_in[1], Normal_ES_in[2]);
Normal_FS_in = normalize(Normal_FS_in);
WorldPos_FS_in = interpolate3D(WorldPos_ES_in[0], WorldPos_ES_in[1], WorldPos_ES_in[2]);
// Displace the vertex along the normal
float Displacement = texture(gDisplacementMap, TexCoord_FS_in.xy).x;
WorldPos_FS_in += Normal_FS_in * Displacement * gDispFactor;
gl_Position = gVP * vec4(WorldPos_FS_in, 1.0);
}
```

FS:

```
varying vec4 position_in_view_space;
uniform sampler2D color_texture;

     void main()
     {
        float dist = distance(position_in_view_space, 
           vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
        if (dist < 1000.0)
        {
            gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
              // color near origin
        }
        else
        {
        gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
           //kill;
           //discard;
           //gl_FragColor = vec4(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0); 
              // color far from origin
        }
     }
```

If for any reason it helps, my PC supports up to (and including) OpenGL 4.0.

Since I have been unable to work out how I am supposedly using a line of code I am not using, I am hoping one of you will be able to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error message is very clear, and the reason is this:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position_VS_in;
[...]
gl_Position = ftransform();
```

`ftransform` is a legacy function which uses the legacy bultin vertex position attribute `gl_Vertex` to transform a vertex according to the also legacy bultin matrix uniforms.

The GL spec also requires the generic vertex attribute 0 to alias the old builtin `gl_Vertex`, so your attribute index 0 is blocked by this and you must not assign some other attribute to this.

Now it is totally unclear why you use `ftransform` here. It seems like you don't want that at all. But I can't be sure about that. But it will definitively not work that way. You shouldn't use that deprecated stuff at all, in my opinion.

**UPDATE 1**

Note that `ftransform` is in princicple equivalent to `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex`, with `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` being a builtin uniform representing the product `P * MV` of the matrices you set for `GL_PROJECTION`  and `GL_MODELVIEW` using the also-deprecated GL matrix stack, and `gl_Vertex` being the builtin vertex position attribute set with `glVertex...`/`glVertexPointer`/`glVertexAttribPointer(0,...)`. Both can be replaced by user-defined attributes/uniforms.

The only twist with `ftransform` is that it is also guaranteed to get the exact same result as rendering with the fixed function pipeline does, for the same inputs. That was useful for multi-pass algorithms where some passed needed to render with shaders, while others used the fixed function pipelinew. Such a function was needed because there might be slight numerical differences if the shader does not use the exact same formula as the GL implementation when rendering without shaders.

Comment: Before I accept your question, could you please tell me a suitable alternative to fTransform()?

Thanks!

Comment: Now java is crashing, but I will make another thread for that issue.
Many thanks for all the help!